# AWS DocumentClient Query Never Called

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am querying a global secondary index like this:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

const docClient =  new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log("EVENT\n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    const requestBody = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const guestName = requestBody.guestName;

    var params = {
        TableName: "realize-guests",
        IndexName: "GuestName-index",
        KeyConditionExpression: "GuestName = :guestName",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":guestName": guestName
        },
        ProjectionExpression:
            "GuestName, Info, LinkedInUrl, S3ImageUrl, Titles, Company"
    };

    console.log("DEBUG\n" + "Query request: [" + guestName + "]");

    docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(
                "ERROR\nCould not retrieve data from realize-guests\nError is: [" + err + "]");

            callback(null, failure(err));
        } 
        else {
            console.log("DEBUG\n" + "Query complete: [" + data + "]");

            callback(null, success(data));
        }
    });
};
```

Surprisingly, the **docClient.query** does not seem to be called or it goes off into space as the logs show the following:

```
16:30:25 START RequestId: bd2232f1-bf26-48f5-8e22-809eb41bd67a Version: $LATEST
16:30:25 2019-08-27T16:30:25.125Z bd2232f1-bf26-48f5-8e22-809eb41bd67a  DEBUG Query request: [Bob Smith]
16:30:25 END RequestId: bd2232f1-bf26-48f5-8e22-809eb41bd67a
16:30:25 REPORT RequestId: bd2232f1-bf26-48f5-8e22-809eb41bd67a Duration: 813.90 ms Billed Duration: 900 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 75 MB
```

The logs never show an ERR or a DEBUG statement that indicates that the **docClient.query** had executed/completed and I am stumped as to the reason.

As an aside, I can make the same query through the AWS CLI and retrieve the necessary data.

Thoughts?

Comment: how is your lambda setup? is it inside VPC? is your handler defined correctly?

Comment: It is set up through an API Gateway.

Comment: You mean it is triggered through an API Gateway. I was asking about how is it setup?

Comment: See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted your question.  It is set up as No VPC.

Comment: What happens when you try to execute the function manually using "Test" button. Does it work as expected?

Comment: try putting your call `docClient.query` inside `try-catch` and see if there is an error. I don't see anything wrong with the call.

Comment: I did and see my log entries stating I am entering/leaving the try block successfully with no actual docClient.query call.

Comment: Some thoughts ... You are console logging EVENT but I don't see it in your logs. Double check your VPCness. Comment out callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop and re-test with the defaults. Maybe issue a different DynamoDB call like describeTable() to see if it completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of callbacks I would use async/await. What you are describing sounds like a problem with the asynchronous nature of the query:

Your function would look like this:

```
module.exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: "realize-guests",
    IndexName: "GuestName-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "GuestName = :guestName",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":guestName": guestName
    },
    ProjectionExpression:
        "GuestName, Info, LinkedInUrl, S3ImageUrl, Titles, Company"
  };

  try {
    const data = await docClient.query(params).promise();
    return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ params, data }) };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      error: `Could not query: ${error.stack}`
    };
  }
};
```